# inviscid Burgers' Shock Solution using Vanishing Viscosity Method

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Ok,  lets say I am going to solve the following equation:

$u_t + (\frac{u^2}{2})_x = \epsilon u_{xx}$

which connects the end conditions $u_-=1$ and $u_+ = 0$. According to my understanding
of the method, the travelling wave is given by the following equation:

$2 \epsilon\frac{dU}{dy} = U^2 + U $

Where $U(y) = u(x,t) $ and $y := x - t/2 $, the solution is:

$u(x,t) = U(x - t/2) = \frac{1}{1+\exp{\frac{x - t/2}{2 \epsilon}}} $

If you take the limit of $\epsilon$ to zero, then (if I am not mistaken):

$u(x, t) = U(x - t/2) = 1/2 $

(...) And here I got stuck, I mean, I know that the solution $u(x,t)$ for inviscid burgers' is one on the left hand side of the shock $y=t/2$ and zero otherwise; but following the aforementioned analysis, I don't find a connection between the limit I got and the actual solution of the problem. Can you help me with the logic of this problem?

PS.: I am just an enthusiast on PDEs, and my background is definentely no mathematics, so please try not to be too harsh on me :)

Comment: A couple of things you can determine the shock time when you get infinite gradient of the solution. Why do you expect the solution be the same for $u$ when you take $\epsilon$ to zero? I will work on this when I get home.

Comment: Also taking the limit of the solution is 1 not $\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake taking the limit $\epsilon\to0$. Note that 
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\exp(a/\epsilon) =\begin{cases} \infty \quad &a>0 \\
0\quad & a<0 \\ 1 \quad & a=0\end{cases}$$
Hence,  the limit of $\dfrac{1}{ 1+\exp((x-t/2)/\epsilon )}$ is 
$$u(x,t) =\begin{cases} 0 \quad &x>t/2 \\
1\quad & x<t/2 \\ 1/2 \quad & x=t/2\end{cases}$$
in agreement with what you know about the inviscid equation.

Comment: Hahahaha, I knew I was mistaken with that limit. Anyhow, for a guy who hasn't taken more than algebra I feel happy of what I obtained. Plus, thank god I found you guys. I will be bothering you in the future.